# JS как запустить анимацию из css файла?

Tags: javascript, css

Есть анимация в css фале:

```
    .pointImg{
        position: absolute ;
        width: 8%;
        margin: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
        -webkit-animation: pulsing 1s infinite;
        animation: pulsing 1s infinite;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes pulsing {
    0% {
      -webkit-transform: scale(0, 0);
      transform: scale(0, 0)
    }
    50% {
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.0, 1.0);
      transform: scale(1.0, 1.0);
    }
    100% {
      -webkit-transform: scale(0, 0);
      transform: scale(0, 0);
    }
}

@keyframes pulsing{
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0, 0);
        transform: scale(0, 0)
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.0, 1.0);
        transform: scale(1.0, 1.0);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0, 0);
        transform: scale(0, 0);
    }
}
```

как из скрипта включить и выключить эту анимацию при нажатии на другую картинку (не класса pointImg)?
Знаю что событие .onclick но не могу разобраться как включить анимацию заново.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно создать класс содержащий эту анимацию, например:

```
pulsing-img {
   animation: pulsing 1s infinite;
   transition: transfrom .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

И на событие добавлять/убирать этот класс(хоть transition лучше добавить изначально к картинке, что бы не дергалась)